# Openshift memory limit is forbidden

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, openshift, prometheus

I would like to increase the memory from 20 to 40 but this error (screenshot at the bottom) keeps coming up and when I google I can't find anything that matches the error.

[image]

Does anyone have an idea which ratio is meant here in the screenshot with the error?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your current config, your memory limit can not be 4 times larger than your memory request.
You can increase your `request.memory` to `10` so it will be maximum 4 times lower than the limit.